# Why commas and underscore is using in Golang. Explain the line 12 in the below code?

Tags: string, go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := scanner.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println("Hello, World.")
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment on the line you're wondering about, and try to describe your thought about the line and what problems you have about it. Also, the title should be a short summary of your question or problem, and the main question should be inside the question body. Please also refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 2):

Golang can return multiple values that is why there is a comma. There are two variables being returned by `scanner.ReadString`.

The reason for the underscore is because the variable isn't being used. This is also known as the **blank identifier**.

I suggest you to take a look at https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values

Answer (score 2):

`ReadString` returns `string` and `error`. An underscore is used when you don't care about some return values. In the above example, error is ignored using `_`. This is required because in Go, every variable declared should have a usage or else the compilation will fail. `_` is a trick to ignore some return values.